# show window notification with datagrid or table format data in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I need to show a windows notification with datagrid or table formatted data and windows form should run background 24/7.

I need call web service timely manner for every 15 mins and read the data show on windows notification with datagrid.

Please let me know, how to do this?

Comment: The problem with this type of question is that it is too broad. Each element has a great amount of info to be learned/discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a windows service that runs every `15` minutes

```
using System.Timers;

Timer tmrExecutor = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
      tmrExecutor.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tmrExecutor_Elapsed); // adding Event
      tmrExecutor.Interval = 15000; // Set your time here 
      tmrExecutor.Enabled = true;
      tmrExecutor.Start();
}

private void tmrExecutor_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      //call your web-service here
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
      tmrExecutor.Enabled = false;
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/540617/windowsplusserviceplustoplusrunpluseveryplusoneplu

Then for datagrid forms, generally

1. Create a windows forms with required buttons and events.
2. Then create a `DataGridView` object and bind your data to it.
3. Populate your windows with this data.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

But since you need to display a form , you may not be able to use the service directly.
Create a windows form application, then use the service to invoke your application every `15` minutes